# CSS background image is not working as expected

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, background-color

For some reason image background set via `background` is not working.

Developer tools in both Chrome and Firefox are showing that the image background set and the link to the image is working, but for some reason it is not showing.

```css
.footer-mold { 
    background: url('http://www.example.com/images/footer-bg.jpg') no-repeat left top;
}
```

Here is a link to site - https://www.pamoldremoval.com/blog/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of `.footer-mold` is 0, since everything inside is floating and you don't clear anything.

One solution would be add

```css
.footer-mold::after {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
```

to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a space at image filename, it will make your image disappear. make sure to rename your image file before uploading process.

for example: "example image.jpg"
better rename it to: "example-image.jpg" or "example_image.jpg"